# Система отправки почты

Tags: email, php, smtp

Здравствуйте, у меня в общем такой вопрос, как правильно отпровлять письмо
в оригинальном коде у гугла написано "Dile*** to: 123@123.ru" А во всех примерах отправки почты просто "To: 123@123.ru"... так как же все-таки правильно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чет я первый вариант не понял, но правильно отправлять

```
To: 123@123.ru
```

Comment: Delivered-To: QuissR@gmail.com // Почта получателя - google версия (оригинальный код письма если посмотреть)
а вот такой во всех уроках:
To: QuissR@gmail.com

я поэтому и интересуюсь...

Comment: Delivered-To: QuissR@gmail.com мне кажется добавляется самой почтой.